GRPC installation in Laravel Docker
I am a beginner in docker . I want to install docker into existing laravel project . The problem is that I want to install grpc for firebase . But , when I install grpc in docker , it's is taking so many time . So , I'm not sure it is true or not.
Docker File
# Use the official PHP image as the base image
FROM php:8.2-fpm

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl \
    libzip-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    autoconf \
    zlib1g-dev \
    libicu-dev \
    libgrpc-dev \
    libprotobuf-dev \
    protobuf-compiler

# Install PHP extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring exif pcntl bcmath gd zip -j$(nproc)

# Install gRPC
RUN pecl install grpc \
    && docker-php-ext-enable grpc

# Install Composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

# Copy existing application directory contents
COPY . /var/www

# Copy existing application directory permissions
COPY --chown=www-data:www-data . /var/www

# Change current user to www
USER www-data


docker-compose.yml
version: '3.9'

services:
    api:
        container_name: htain-thein
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        working_dir: /var/www
        volumes:
            - .:/var/www
            - ./php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
        environment:
            - APP_ENV=local
            - APP_DEBUG=true
            - DB_CONNECTION=${DB_CONNECTION}
            - DB_HOST=${DB_HOST}
            - DB_PORT=${DB_PORT}
            - DB_DATABASE=${DB_DATABASE}
            - DB_USERNAME=${DB_USERNAME}
            - DB_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
        depends_on:
            - mysql_db
        networks:
            - htain-thein-network

    web_server:
        image: nginx:latest
        volumes:
            - .:/var/www
            - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
        ports:
            - "8000:80"
        depends_on:
            - api
        networks:
            - htain-thein-network

    mysql_db:
        image: mysql:latest
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "3308:3306"
        environment:
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=${DB_DATABASE}
            - MYSQL_USER=${DB_USERNAME}
            - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
        volumes:
            - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
        networks:
            - htain-thein-network

volumes:
    mysql_data:
        driver: local

networks:
    htain-thein-network:
        driver: bridge


nginx.conf
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name localhost;

    root /var/www/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass api:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}


Without grpc , docker file installation is fast but when i put grpc in docker installation , it's taking over 20 min and keep going on .
